# What does a good flag for suspected AI (e.g., ChatGPT) content look like?

Tags: discussion, flags, chatgpt

When flagging a post that I believe is ChatGPT, what information should I include?

If I just raise a *"In need of moderator intervention"* flag and let them know it looks like ChatGPT, is that enough?

If not, with the list of SE-approved heuristics not being made public, how do I know what to put in the flag?

**Important:** *If/When answering, please do not post specific examples of reasons you put in your flags.  See [Why is it a bad idea to tell other users publicly why you believe something is (or is not) from ChatGPT (or other AI)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425578/11810933)*

Comment: Sadly (but also not unexpectedly), in my experience, it's extremely rare for non-mods to flag AI content. (I have seen some other site mods flagging.) It's a bit more common to see comments, but I think a flag with even a mediocre description like "the language is stilted and it seemed suspicious" is better than no flag. Since most users don't have access to the heuristics, it's not expected that their flags will be 100% accurate, but mods appreciate users trying their best to keep the site clean.

Comment: Users frequently exposed to AI-generated content will subconsciously pick up its style and patterns, causing these users to start writing in the same way. The false positive rate can be expected to go up.

Comment: @JoachimWagner depends on the specific behaviour. some are probably quite hard to pick up naturally.

Comment: @JoachimWagner That's true, and some I've picked up myself (much to the chagrin of my fellow AI-Team members, I believe).  We should (and I do) definitely keep that in mind when (and if) flagging, and I'm sure the Mods also do as well before taking action.  There have been times I've given the benefit-of-the-doubt to a user based on an answer that appeared to be AI, only to come back a day, week, or month later only to find that they'd posted additional content that was even more obviously AI.  And for others, I'm still not quite sure. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Related: In an answer to [New flag for ChatGPT answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388632/902710), @Laurel makes the point that:

> ... your suggestion prevents the user from giving any details about why the answer is AI generated. These details are very important because **they can considerably shorten the amount of time a moderator spends** on [investigating and acting on the flag].

The best AI flags will included as many details as you can possibly provide on why **you** believe the answer is ChatGPT/AI assisted or generated.  Yes, this can be a time consuming flagging process, especially when you may be flagging several answers (or more).  However, keep in mind that the Moderators who will be reading your flag are dealing with *many times* that number.

A suggested format to try to reduce the time both *you* and the *moderators* spend on the flag:

---

> Suspected AI: [Reason]

or, hopefully:

> Suspected AI: **(1)** A reason **(2)** Another reason **(3)** yet another reason

---

While it's not *required*, numbering and bolding the items makes them easier to read - Flag details get compressed into a wall of text with no line-breaks, so the additional separation can be useful.  My understanding is that the Mods see the flag text in the same formatting that you do in the "Flags" section of your profile.

And details, details, details. If there's a particular place in the answer that you believe is problematic, point it out specifically (e.g., *"2nd paragraph says ..."*).

If you get to the point where you are running out of allowed characters in your flag, some possible aids:

- When referencing another answer on the same site, you can shorten it considerably by dropping the protocol and domain from the link.  For example:

  - `https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388632/902710` (the link to Laurel's answer at the beginning of this answer)
  - Can be shortened to `[1](/a/388632)`
- Obviously, abbreviate (abbr.)
- Use "1" instead of "one" format for numbers.
- Etc.

Comment: "When referencing another answer on the same site..." If you have a detailed explanation for why that answer is also AI, you should go flag it too, which will give you even more room to explain. It's worth keeping in mind that a mod can see all flags on a single user at the same time if they go to the right page.