# Is casting R/A flags on blatant, but uncited, LLM-generated content acceptable?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, offensive, chatgpt

*This is about LLM-generated content that wouldn't otherwise be R/A, not abusive content that happens to be LLM-generated. Also, spam is still spam, even if it's AI-generated.*

For sake of discussion, I'll define "blatant" AI-generated content as "clear to a reasonable user with no access to the heuristics". While I cannot disclose the heuristics, an answer starting with "As an AI language model ..." would qualify as blatant here.

Per [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035)

> A post should be marked as rude or abusive [...] if it contains [...] abuse of the community or system, i.e., a clear violation of the Code of Conduct.

I consider LLM-generated content an abuse of the system and *uncited* content [is a CoC violation per Inauthentic Usage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393682).

> As a rule of thumb, everything that would be out of place in polite discourse is rude or abusive.

If I asked someone a question, and they started their reply with "As an AI language model", I'd consider that impolite. If I messaged a colleague, and they posted a blatantly ChatGPT dump as a reply, I'd consider that rude, and absolutely out of place.

> (under When not to use the flag) The post blatantly violates other site rules. This is what downvotes, close votes, and other flag types are for.

While it's debatable what "other site rules" means, I'd argue it's a CoC violation. We still red flag inappropriate content even if it's also off-topic. (Or, we *shouldn't* close R/A or spam posts, anyways)

Interestingly, there's also [an MSO discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426221/under-what-conditions-is-a-non-mod-allowed-to-vote-to-delete-content-for-suspici) about normal users (without diamonds) casting delete votes on suspected LLM answers. The conclusion there seemed to be "Normal users aren't bound by heuristics, so we can cast delete votes if we want, and disputes can go to Meta. It might be messy, but that's SE's fault here". It was given [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), but I don't see a staff answer there, so IDK to what extent that's policy.

---

Specifically, I'm *not* asking if it's preferred or ideal - it's clear that [custom] mod flags are a better option. But, if I want something blatantly fake gone, and I don't want to wait, may I cast an R/A red flag under the rules for when to use red flags?

Comment: Related: [New flag for ChatGPT answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388587/new-flag-for-chatgpt-answers)

Comment: I have been. It **is** rude and it **is** absuive. Custom mod flags require a mod to deal with it, which is time they don't need to waste on LLM/chatbot garbage.

Comment: The auto generated answers are pure garbage. I'm personally offended by that garbage, so started to flag those as offensive a while ago. Right or wrong? Guess I'll just stop if those flags will start to be declined.

Comment: Related: [What does a good flag for suspected AI (e.g., ChatGPT) content look like?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393236/what-does-a-good-flag-for-suspected-ai-e-g-chatgpt-content-look-like)

Answer (score 6):

I think you answered your own question in quoting:

> Do **not** use this flag if ...
>
> - The post blatantly violates other site rules. This is what downvotes, close votes, and other flag types are for.

If LLM content is not allowed under a particular site's rules, then it should be flagged for Moderator attention.

There's good reason for this -- *We want Moderators to see and be able to take AI-appropriate action on AI answers.*  This means that, when an answer from a user is determined by a Mod to be AI, they can:

1. Not only remove the *answer*, but also ...
2. (Sometimes more importantly) Provide a warning to the user that it is not permitted.
3. If it's a repeat offense, take appropriate additional action, such as potential suspension of the user.

R/A flags can prevent that from happening by allowing deletion of the post without a Moderator ever reviewing it.